# Cannot convert value of type `[String: String?]` to expected argument type `[String: String!]`

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift2, avspeechsynthesizer

Hi i am getting error while appending value to dictornary. I am using `Xcode 7` and `Swift 2`.
**Error Message:**   Cannot convert value of type `[String: String?]` to expected argument type `[String: String!]`

Declaration:

```
var arrVoiceLanguages: [Dictionary<String, String!>] = []
```

following is my function

```
  for voice in AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices() {
        let voiceLanguageCode = (voice as AVSpeechSynthesisVoice).language

        let languageName = NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: voiceLanguageCode)

        let dictionary = ["languageName": languageName, "languageCode": voiceLanguageCode]

        arrVoiceLanguages.append(dictionary)
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

I don't know why people give down vote to this question.!

Comment: See my edited question

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your arrVoiceLanguages variable declared [String:String!] type and NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey() function's return type is String?.

So you can try this (I added ! at end to unwrap value).

```
let languageName = NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: voiceLanguageCode)!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `arrVoiceLanguages` array type should be:

```
var arrVoiceLanguages = [[String: String?]]()
```

Or you need to unwrap `languageName` this way:

```
guard let languageName = NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: voiceLanguageCode) else {return}
```

Because `NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: voiceLanguageCode)` return optional string.

By unwrapping `languageName` you don't need to change type of your `arrVoiceLanguages` array. And your code will be:

```
var arrVoiceLanguages: [Dictionary<String, String!>] = []

    for voice in AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices() {
        let voiceLanguageCode = (voice as AVSpeechSynthesisVoice).language

        guard let languageName = NSLocale.currentLocale().displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: voiceLanguageCode) else {return}

        let dictionary = ["languageName": languageName, "languageCode": voiceLanguageCode]

        arrVoiceLanguages.append(dictionary)
    }
```